# NoHttpResponseException on uploading file to S3 (camel-aws)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, apache-camel

I am trying to upload around 10 GB file from my local machine to S3 (inside a camel route). Although file gets uploaded in around 3-4 minutes, but it also throwing following exception:

```
2014-06-26 13:53:33,417 | INFO  | ads.com/outbound | FetchRoute                       | 167 - com.ut.ias - 2.0.3 | Download complete to local. Pushing file to S3
2014-06-26 13:54:19,465 | INFO  | manager-worker-6 | AmazonHttpClient                 | 144 - org.apache.servicemix.bundles.aws-java-sdk - 1.5.1.1 | Unable to execute HTTP request: The target server failed to respond
org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: The target server failed to respond
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:95)[142:org.apache.httpcomponents.httpclient:4.2.5]
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:62)[142:org.apache.httpcomponents.httpclient:4.2.5]
        at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:254)[141:org.apache.httpcomponents.httpcore:4.2.4]
        at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:289)[141:org.apache.httpcomponents.httpcore:4.2.4]
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultClientConnection.java:252)[142:org.apache.httpcomponents.httpclient:4.2.5]
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.receiveResponseHeader(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:191)[142:org.apache.httpcomponents.httpclient:4.2.5]
        at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:300)[141:org.apache.httpcomponents.httpcore:4.2.4]
.......
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)[:1.7.0_55]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)[:1.7.0_55]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)[:1.7.0_55]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)[:1.7.0_55]
    2014-06-26 13:55:08,991 | INFO  | ads.com/outbound | FetchRoute                       | 167 - com.ut.ias - 2.0.3 | Upload complete.
```

Due to which camel route doesn't stop and it is continuously throwing InterruptedException:

```
2014-06-26 13:55:11,182 | INFO  | ads.com/outbound | SftpOperations                   | 110 - org.apache.camel.camel-ftp - 2.12.1 | JSCH -> Disconnecting from cxportal.integralads.com port 22
2014-06-26 13:55:11,183 | INFO  | lads.com session | SftpOperations                   | 110 - org.apache.camel.camel-ftp - 2.12.1 | JSCH -> Caught an exception, leaving main loop due to Socket closed
2014-06-26 13:55:11,183 | WARN  | lads.com session | eventadmin                       | 139 - org.apache.felix.eventadmin - 1.3.2 | EventAdmin: Exception: java.lang.InterruptedException
java.lang.InterruptedException
        at EDU.oswego.cs.dl.util.concurrent.LinkedQueue.offer(Unknown Source)[139:org.apache.felix.eventadmin:1.3.2]
        at EDU.oswego.cs.dl.util.concurrent.PooledExecutor.execute(Unknown Source)[139:org.apache.felix.eventadmin:1.3.2]
        at org.apache.felix.eventadmin.impl.tasks.DefaultThreadPool.executeTask(DefaultThreadPool.java:101)[139:org.apache.felix.eventadmin:1.3.2]
        at org.apache.felix.eventadmin.impl.tasks.AsyncDeliverTasks.execute(AsyncDeliverTasks.java:105)[139:org.apache.felix.eventadmin:1.3.2]
        at org.apache.felix.eventadmin.impl.handler.EventAdminImpl.postEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:100)[139:org.apache.felix.eventadmin:1.3.2]
        at org.apache.felix.eventadmin.impl.adapter.LogEventAdapter$1.logged(LogEventAdapter.java:281)[139:org.apache.felix.eventadmin:1.3.2]
        at org.ops4j.pax.logging.service.internal.LogReaderServiceImpl.fire(LogReaderServiceImpl.java:134)[50:org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-service:1.7.1]
        at org.ops4j.pax.logging.service.internal.LogReaderServiceImpl.fireEvent(LogReaderServiceImpl.java:126)[50:org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-service:1.7.1]
        at org.ops4j.pax.logging.service.internal.PaxLoggingServiceImpl.handleEvents(PaxLoggingServiceImpl.java:180)[50:org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-service:1.7.1]
        at org.ops4j.pax.logging.service.internal.PaxLoggerImpl.inform(PaxLoggerImpl.java:145)[50:org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-service:1.7.1]
        at org.ops4j.pax.logging.internal.TrackingLogger.inform(TrackingLogger.java:86)[18:org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-api:1.7.1]
        at org.ops4j.pax.logging.slf4j.Slf4jLogger.info(Slf4jLogger.java:476)[18:org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-api:1.7.1]
        at org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpOperations$JSchLogger.log(SftpOperations.java:359)[110:org.apache.camel.camel-ftp:2.12.1]
        at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.run(Session.java:1621)[109:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.jsch:0.1.49.1]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)[:1.7.0_55]
```

Please see my code below and let me know, where I am going wrong:

```
TransferManager tm = new TransferManager(
        S3Client.getS3Client());
// TransferManager processes all transfers asynchronously,
// so this call will return immediately.
Upload upload = tm.upload(
        Utils.getProperty(Constants.BUCKET),
        getS3Key(file.getName()), file);

try {
    upload.waitForCompletion();
    logger.info("Upload complete.");
} catch (AmazonClientException amazonClientException) {
    logger.warn("Unable to upload file, upload was aborted.");
    amazonClientException.printStackTrace();
}
```

The stacktrace doesn't even have any reference to my code, hence couldn't determine where the issue is. 
Any help or pointer would be really appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Can you just aws-sdk to upload the file to see if there any thing wrong with your account setting? Can you past your camel route?